# Processing dictionary with zip function keeping the same structure in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, bert-language-model

I have a dictionary where each key is mapped to a list of arrays, except the key "reference" which is just an array of Integers.

cls["input_ids"], cls["attention_masks"],  cls["labels"], cls["reference"]

Each row of a key is linked to the row of the other keys (this is a modified output of a Bert tokenizer)

I would like to filter out some rows by the reference value and keeping in output the same dictionary structure, right now the only way I manage to do this is like this:
I put some random data to give an idea

```
cls= {"input_ids":[[22,22,22],[33,33,33]], "attention_masks":[[22,22,22],[33,33,33]], "reference":[1,0], "labels":[[[22,22,22],[33,33,33]]]}
mcp = {"input_ids":[], "attention_masks":[], "reference":[], "labels":[]}

        for el in zip(cls["input_ids"], cls["attention_masks"], cls["reference"], cls["labels"]):
            if el[2] == 1:
                mcp["input_ids"].append(el[0])
                mcp["attention_masks"].append(el[1])
                mcp["reference"].append(el[2])
                mcp["labels"].append(el[3])
```

But I really don't like this code and I was wondering if there was a prettier way of doing this.

Comment: Your snippet does not compile.

Comment: Each key is a list of arrays? Can you provide an example of what `cls` could be?

Comment: Changed code to give an idea, added some random data. Now compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your values all have the same length, I'd suggest to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) which is made for that kind of modification.

```py
import pandas as pd

cls= {"input_ids":[[22,22,22],[33,33,33]], 
      "attention_masks":[[22,22,22],[33,33,33]], 
      "reference":[1,0], 
      "labels":[[22,22,22],[33,33,33]] # I assume this is what you meant
      }

# Turn the data into a dataframe which is sth like a table
df = pd.DataFrame(cls)
```

This is what `df` looks like:

```py
>>> df
      input_ids attention_masks  reference        labels
0  [22, 22, 22]    [22, 22, 22]          1  [22, 22, 22]
1  [33, 33, 33]    [33, 33, 33]          0  [33, 33, 33]
```

You can access the values like `df['reference']` and filter the data, e.g., like this:

```py
>>> df[df['reference']==1]
      input_ids attention_masks  reference        labels
0  [22, 22, 22]    [22, 22, 22]          1  [22, 22, 22]
```

If you need it as dictionary:

```py
>>> df[df['reference']==1].to_dict()
{'input_ids': {0: [22, 22, 22]},
 'attention_masks': {0: [22, 22, 22]},
 'reference': {0: 1},
 'labels': {0: [22, 22, 22]}}
```

Comment: exactly what i was searching for. Thanks